# ActionBar dissapears when using sepcified resource folder

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am writing app with `android:minSdkVersion="14"`. Everything went fine until I tryed to add support for tablets.

When I created **values-sw600dp** folder and copied there the default `dimens.xml` file from **values** folder and tried to run the app on tablet, it started behave differently even when those dimensions file were identical. 
`ActionBar` was gone, `getActionBar()` started to return `null`, `EditText` fields are orange framed instead of that blue underline, whole app design now looks like its on android 2.0.

On smaller devices where it still used default **values** folder everything is ok.

For testing, I tried to lower the **600** threshold (in *values-sw600dp*) to **300** to force this folder to be used even on smaller devices and result was same. `ActionBar` gone etc...

Sorry for english and thank you for answer

Comment: which version of android your tablet runs ?

Comment: Tablet is on 4.0.4. It behaves correctly when the specific folder isnt there and it just uses deafault values. Problems starts when i suplly values-sw600dp folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found solution to my problem. I accidentally coppied line:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
```

into my `dimens.xml` file in folder *values-sw600dp*, which caused application to use `Theme.Light` instead of my default theme `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` in folder *values-v14*. I don´t know how it got there but I am glad I found it.